# Dynamic collection generation with linq

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I wonder if linq already contains something to generate collections on the fly.

Lets say i want a dynamic collection of GUIDs, I currently use something like the following code for it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(Func<T> generator)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        yield return generator();
    }
}

var someIds = MyLinqExtensions.Generate(Guid.NewGuid).Take(10);
```

As such a construct is really handy sometimes, I'd rather not re-implement the wheel if such thing exists already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx#Y800) to generate a sequence of ints an then use [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) to instantiate the item:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => Guid.NewGuid());
```

Comment: I thought about such a thing too but I didn't like two things about it:
- It has an additional layer of enumeration I don't need.
- It doesn't have the endless source of whatever feeling :)

Comment: @Fionn, true. If this is what you are after, I think your implementation is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe LINQ contains anything like that at the moment. The closest you could come would be:

```
var someIds = Enumerable.Repeat(0, int.MaxValue)
                        .Select(ignored => Guid.NewGuid)
                        .Take(10);
```

Comment: Seems like this would be a good feature for the next version then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the InteractiveExtensions (IX) from the same people that brought you LINQ and RX. Among other things, it includes a Generate method similar to what you are proposing:

public static IEnumerable Generate(TState initialState, Func condition, Func iterate, Func resultSelector)

I did a brief writeup of IX at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Ix-Interactive-Extensions-return